# SpecFlow Table.CreateInstance returns null

Tags: specflow

I am using SpecFlow version 1.9.0
I have a POCO class

```
    public class MerchantContactDetails 
{
    public string Title;
    public string Firstname;
    public string Lastname;
    public string Companyposition;
    public string Phonecode;
    public string Phoneno;
    public string Mobilecode;
    public string Mobileno;
    public string Email;
 }
```

My Specflow feature is

```
Scenario: Sample contact
When I add a new contact information
| title | firstname | lastname | companyposition | phonecode | phoneno | mobilecode | mobileno | email                |
| Mr    | Grim      | Smith    | Director        | 1 (US)    | 12345   | 1 (US)     | 45678    | Grim.Smith@gmail.com |
```

And my step definitions has

```
[When(@"I add a new contact information")]
    public void WhenIAddANewContactInformation(Table table)
    {
       MerchantContactDetails ContactDetails = table.CreateInstance<MerchantContactDetails>();
    }
```

When the scenario is executed, I see ContactDetails is set to null. However object table has Rows count set 1 and I could access values explicitly by call

```
table.Rows[0]["title"] => this works fine
```

only table.CreateInstance(); returns null

Please can someone point me in the right direction..?

Best Regards

Comment: have you tried making the properties match the table columns including the case. you have 'title' and `Title`

Answer (score 4):

Finally I was able to find a solution. Turning all the fileds into properties makes SpecFlow to fill the object. 
The class definition now looks

```
public class MerchantContactDetails
{
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public string Firstname{get;set;}
    public string Lastname{get;set;}
    public string Companyposition{get;set;}
    public string Phonecode{get;set;}
    public string Phoneno{get;set;}
    public string Mobilecode{get;set;}
    public string Mobileno{get;set;}
    public string Email{get;set;}
 }
```

@ Sam Holder, thanks for your suggestion. The names of the columns can be case-insensitive. May also contain spaces. For example in SpecFlow feature we may have First Name, and it perfectly matches the class property firstname.